# Regular expression in java script for possitive and non decimal

Tags: javascript

I need to implement java script code for field validation.
It should allow Only positive numbers (i.e no negative or alphanumeric) and no decimals.
Please provide inputs for the same(regular expression).

Comment: `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var regEx = /^\d+$/g;

regEx.test(123);//true
regEx.test(-123);// false
regEx.test("123a");//false
regEx.test("123.2");//false
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
var a = new RegEx(^\d+$)
a.test(-10); //false
```